# Why can't I create a public folder?

Tags: permissions, exchange-2003, public-folders

I have a need to create a new Exchange public folder, as a sub folder to a folder that I'm already the owner of.

When ever I try (from Outlook 2007) to create a new public folder, I'm told I don't have persmission.

Outlook doesn't let me view the permissions of this folder, however it lets me view permissions of other folders that I'm owner of. Both ESM and PFDAVAdmin both report that my regular (i.e. non domain admin account) is the owner of the folder.

Our set up is as follows: Exchange 2003 running on Server 2003, Windows 2008 R2 domain. Windows XP Desktop, Outlook 2007. Everything fully patched.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Delving deeper into the permissions (CTRL Click on 'Client permissions' dialog in ESM), the advanced tab showed some odd deny entries. Once removed, public folder creation is back to normal.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing. Talk to you admin, you obviously (read the error) dont ahve the permission to create another folder in there.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't too clear, but I am the admin, how would I be using ESM and PFDAVAdmin on the exchange server if I wasn't? As stated, the permissions appear correct, yet it doesn't work.